# How to use sets in javascript and get same result

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

In javascript i have 2 seta and from set A remove set B

Set A : 7, 8, 9, 10
Set B: 8,9

Result should be :7,10

using var availableA = [...new Set([...workingA].filter(x => !b1.has(x)))];

result is not correct
what can i use else for difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```js
function padHours(str) {
    const [minutes, seconds] = str.match(/\d{1,2}/g);
    return (minutes.length < 2 ? '0' + minutes : minutes) + ':' + seconds;
}

const a = new Set(['07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00'].map(padHours));
const b = new Set(['07:00', '8:00', '9:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00'].map(padHours));

// Converting to an array allows to filter (which is not possible on Sets)

const arr = [...a, ...b].filter(x => !a.has(x) || !b.has(x));

console.log(arr);

// And if you absolutely want the result as a Set

const result = new Set(arr);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: a is : 07:00,08:00,09:00,10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00,14:00,15:00,16:00,17:00,18:00  b:07:00,8:00,9:00,15:00,16:00,17:00,11:00,12:00,13:00 arr: 08:00,09:00,10:00,14:00,18:00,8:00,9:00  don't know why i can't get the right result

Comment: because you have `8:00`, `08:00`, `9:00`, `09:00`

Comment: so how can i fix ? it suppose to have as result 10,14,18

Comment: just compare what is comparable, dont compare `8:00` to `08:00`, dont compare `9:00` to `09:00`

Comment: do you have any suhhestion how to compare to sets and to create new array with different data ?

Comment: I've added an example on how you could format the compared strings in order to make them comparable